# Frontend api request returns 404 in aws ec2 but working in localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, axios, mern

I am currently working on a full stack project in MERN stack. So I launched the project in an aws ec2 instance. Even though I did all according to the tutorial (https://youtu.be/rE8mJ1OYjmM?si=EiS-O4Ckg25VOS2x) my frontend doesn't connect to the backend.
I always get '**Request failed with status code 404**' error in the chrome dev tools and nothing more.
This is the frontend page code
locations.jsx

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import LocationsCard from "../components/locationsCard";
import Navbar from "../components/navbar";
import Footer from "../components/footer";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Locations = () => {
    let path = window.location;
    const [locations, setLocations] = useState(null);
    const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        //In this code it checks whether there is a filter parameter. If have a filter parameter else block activates
        if (path.search === "") {
            axios
                .get("/api/shop/find")
                .then((res) => setLocations(res.data))
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        } else {
            let params = Object.fromEntries([...searchParams]);
            console.log(params);
            axios
                .post(`/api/shop/findInStore/`, { ...params })
                .then((res) => setLocations(res.data))
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="">
            <Navbar />
            <div className="locations-page">
                <div className="locations-heading">
                    {path.search !== "" ? (
                        <h1>Shops near me</h1>
                    ) : (
                        <h1>Select a shop you wish!</h1>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className="locations-container">
                    {locations?.map((location, i) => {
                        return <LocationsCard location={location} key={i} />;
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Locations;
```

This is my shopRoute.js file

```
const Shop = require('../models/Shop');

const router = require('express').Router();
/ Find shops 

router.get('/find', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const shops = await Shop.find(); if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(501).send({
                message: `MongoDB Exception: ${err}`,
            });
        } else {
            console.log(codes);
            res.json(shops);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
});

//Find all shops which serves a specific food;
router.post('/findInStore/', async (req, res) => {
    let query = req.body;
    console.log(query)
    try {
        const queryObject = {};
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(query)) {
            if (value === 'true' || value === 'false') {
                queryObject[key] = value;
            } else {
                queryObject[key] = { $regex: new RegExp(value, 'i') }
            }
        }
        const shops = await Shop.find(queryObject);
        res.status(200).json(shops)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

I also added the following in my client package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

The following is my server.js file code:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const productRoute = require('./routes/prodcutRoute');
const orderRoute = require('./routes/orderRoute');
const shopRoute = require('./routes/shopRoute');
const stripeRoute = require('./routes/stripeRoute');
const orderEmailRoute = require('./routes/orderEmailRoute');
const receiptRoute = require('./routes/recieptRoute');
const distanceRoute = require('./routes/distanceRoute');
const emailRoute = require('./routes/emailRoute');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}
).then(() => console.log('DB connection successful')).catch((err) => console.log(err))

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));

app.use('/api/shop', shopRoute);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started listening ${port}`);
});
```

I am wondering if there is a bug in my code.
Please let me know if there is any bug in my code.